# How to disambiguate repeated strings by appending varying length strings?

Tags: r

I saw the clever code submitted by Gabor G. in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062748/disambiguate-non-unique-elements-in-a-character-vector/35063121#35063121) about disambiguation of strings. His answer, slightly modified, is:

```
uniqName <- function(x){
thenames <- ave(x,x,FUN = function(z){
    znam <- if (length(z) == 1) z else sprintf("%s%02d", z, seq_along(z))
    return(znam)
})
return(thenames)
}
```

I wanted to go for an "invisible" version of that, and tried to come up with a compact function that would append N spaces to the (N+1)th occurrence of a name.
(Gabor's code calculates an integer and appends that, so the number of characters appended is constant).  The best I could do was the following clunky function ("fatit")

```
spacify <- function (x){
    fatit <-function(x){
         k = vector(length=length(x))
         for(jp in 1:length(x)){
            k[jp]=sprintf('%s%s',x[jp],paste0(rep(' ',jp),collapse=''))
         }
         return(k)
     }
     spaceOut <- ave(x,x, FUN = function(z) if (length(z) == 1) z else fatit(z) )
     return(spaceOut)
    }
```

Is there some cleaner, more compact, way to set the number of characters to append based on `length(z)` in the `fatit` function ?

Note:

```
uniqName(foo)
[1] "a01" "b01" "c01" "a02" "b02" "a03" "c02" "d"   "e" 

spacify(foo)
[1] "a "   "b "   "c "   "a  "  "b  "  "a   " "c  "  "d"    "e"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take advantage of `make.unique` by striping the numbers that make the characters unique, and using them (... + 1) as reference as to how many characters to append, i.e.

```
i1 <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', make.unique(x)))
i1[is.na(i1)] <- 0 #because where there is no number it returns NA
paste0(x, sapply(i1 + 1, function(i) paste(rep(' ', each = i), collapse = '')))
#[1] "a "   "b "   "c "   "a  "  "b  "  "a   " "c  "  "d "   "e "
```

Comment: This works unless there are digits in the original strings.  I suspect a "Bulletproof" regex would have to look for   the text pattern   `[.][0-9]{1,}$`   to guarantee that neither numerals nor dots in the original names mess things up.  I'm not deprecating your original solution, which is very clean and works for the example I posted.

Comment: Or this: `idx <- as.numeric(gsub('.*correcthorsebatterystaple(\\d+$)', '\\1', make.unique(bar,sep='correcthorsebatterystaple')))`

Answer (score 1):

We can take advantage of the `stri_pad_right` function from `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
f <- function(x){
    ave(x, x, FUN = function(z){
        if(length(z) == 1) z else stri_pad_right(z, nchar(z[1]) + seq_along(z))
    })
}

x <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e')
f(x)
# [1] "a "   "b "   "c "   "a  "  "b  "  "a   " "c  "  "d"    "e"
```

Using `stringr::str_pad(..., side = 'right')` is conceptually similar.

Comment: If I don't select this answer, it's only because I'm a "minimalist" who likes solutions that only require the `base` install.  That is a great string function in there.